# How do SQL Server allocate RAM for Job steps?

Tags: sql-server-2016, memory, sql-server-2019, sql-server-agent

I am working with SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2019 Standard edition. We have this job that's been there for a while. It used to be small but now it runs dozens of `SELECT/DELETE` statements. (There is no `GO` separator between the statements.)

- I was wondering how does SQL Server allocate RAM for job steps?
- Will SQL try to allocate the RAM for the whole step at once?
- Or will it allocate the RAM for each query as it runs the step?
- Considering RAM usage, would it be better to do different steps to the job?

I will probably end up separating the job anyway, if only for monitoring purposes. But since we're using SQL Standard edition, I monitor RAM usage closely and couldn't find information on the allocation inside SQL Agent jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queries running from SQL Server Agent are just exactly the same as queries running from any other client, such as SQL Server Management Studio.

Copy-and-paste the queries from the job into an SSMS query window, turn on Actual Execution Plans, and see what shows up.  For giggles, you could then add batch separators between each query, run it again, and see what difference it makes.

SQL Server allocates memory on a per-query basis, not for the entire batch at once.